# Hiding the JSON payload from /api and auth/ routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, security

Is there a way to protect the api route when a user enter that in the url? Please see my screen shot. I know there's a way to authenticate a user in the backend using a middleware but it seems like if the data can be viewed publicly, the JSON payloads can also be viewed publicly. I'm still new to this, so forgive me if this question has already been asked. I use Node.js, React, Express and Sequelize.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? I'm assuming that you do not want your `/api/users` route to be accessible to the public. Is that correct?

Comment: Hi Sravanth Chebrolu, yes, correct! I know there's a way to authenticate a user and grand him/her access to certain information. But for public data that's accessible to the public, I also don't want users to be able to see JSON payloads by typing api/something in the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you do not want your `/api/users` route to be accessible to the public, I think this solution should work, although there might be better solutions.

You can try protecting specific routes based on the `role` of the user. I suggest you add a `user_role` field to your user schema, and create a middleware function that only allows logged in users with a specific role to access the route, as shown in the pseudo code below:

```
function (req, res, next) {
   // Check if user is logged in and is assigned the role you want to allow.
   if(user is logged in) return next();
   else throw error; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I was able to protect my API route in the backend depends on user authorization. I clarified it with my instructor, so basically if the payloads are public (accessible to everyone), then when the payloads will be visible in the browser if entering api/publicPayloads in the url. That's actually not something we can do. When it comes to sensitive information like user payloads, the API middleware is very effective! :-)